Spring Integration TCP Server to Client request response
I've a use case where I need to make requests to an external system using TCP socket and wait for response. I know that Spring Integration Outbound Gateway can be used if I'm connected as a client.
But as per the requirement of the external system, I need to start my service as a TCP server and external system will create multiple active connections to my service. Now whenever I needed, I should use one of the active connections to make a request to the external system.
I know the alternative approach of Adapters, but I think they are not Direct Channel and will be working asynchronously. And I will have to choose one of the connections manually in a thread safe way. Does Spring Integration provides any synchronous and thread safe approach for the Servlet to Client request/response pattern? Or is it better to go with plain java socket connection in this scenario?
TIA
Tried using Spring integration gateway, but for server it only supports Inbound Gateway

Yes, you have to use Collaborating Outbound and Inbound Channel Adapters: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/ip/correlation.html.
You still can achieve a sync logic from your application perspective via @MessagingGateway to produce a message to the TcpSendingMessageHandler which chosen ip_connectionId. Send this message into an aggregator as well. And then on receiving from the TcpReceivingChannelAdapter you send that message to that aggregator for correlation between request and reply to complete the group. The result of this aggregator must go to the replyChannel of the request message to relay it back into the original @MessagingGateway as a return value.
We probably don't have such a sample, but I believe that your idea withe plain Java sockets would lead to similar correlation solution.
Not sure what information you transfer over the network to be able to correlate reply back. If you can do that only based on the mentioned ip_connectionId, then you need to implement connection pool logic to have an exclusive access to them until reply comes back on this connection. Then you indeed can correlated in the aggregator using this ip_connectionId indication.

Thanks @Artem. It's payment messages we send over TCP and the extenal system respond with payment status. It is also possible that sometimes the external system could send some admin messages to us without any request we sent.

So, yeah... Indeed this is an async pattern with collaborating TCP channel adapters. For those admin messages you would need to implement a router to catch them as one-way messages. Otherwise router it to the aggregator treating as a reply to previously sent request.

Hi @Artem, I'm trying to implement the suggestion you provided. What should I set as "OuputChannel" for TcpReceivingChannelAdapter?

The regular DirectChannel is fully OK.

I tried using the defaultRequestChannel mentioned in the MessagingGateway. But unfortunately gateway method caller was not receiving any response.
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "tcpChannel")
public interface TcpGateway {
String sendAndReceive(@Payload String message, @Header(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID) String cid);

}

public MessageChannel tcpChannel () {return new DirectChannel(); }
@Bean
public TcpReceivingChannelAdapter tcpReceivingAdapter() {
TcpReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new TcpReceivingChannelAdapter();
adapter.setConnectionFactory(serverConnectionFactory());
adapter.setOutputChannel(tcpChannel ());
return adapter;
}

The multi-line code in the comments is not readable. Looks like you are diving to implementation details. That deserves its own SO thread.
